# Getting general location of user with google maps

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps

I'm trying to get a general location of the user, reasons irrelevant, but I can't use the API to get their location. I've tried to parse the data associated with the IP, but if I have the $.getJson() outside of the initMap() function, the variables aren't changed and if inside initMap(), initMap() isn't recognised as a function.

tl:dr - how do I call the $.getJSON from inside the initMap() function?

Here's What I've tried:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;; "></div>
        <!-- G-Maps box-sizing: border-box; -->

        <script>
            var usrLat = 0;
            var usrLon = 0;

            function initMap() {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 6,

                    $.getJSON("https://freegeoip.net/json/", function (data) {
                                        usrLat = parseFloat(data.latitude);
                                        usrLon = parseFloat(data.longitude);
                                        console.log(usrLon + ", " + usrLat);
                                        });

                    center: {lat: usrLat, lng: usrLon},
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    navigationControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    scaleControl: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                    mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'terrain']
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the position of your call (inside the data structure), plus the semicolon on the end of the call.

Try this instead

```
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;; "></div>
    <!-- G-Maps box-sizing: border-box; -->

    <script>
        var usrLat = 0;
        var usrLon = 0;

        function initMap() {

            $.getJSON("https://freegeoip.net/json/", function (data) {
                                    usrLat = parseFloat(data.latitude);
                                    usrLon = parseFloat(data.longitude);
                                    console.log(usrLon + ", " + usrLat);
                                    });
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 6,
                center: {lat: usrLat, lng: usrLon},
                mapTypeControl: true,
                scrollwheel: false,
                navigationControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                draggable: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'terrain']
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, the posted code won't work (you need the map initialization in the callback function).

Comment: ah yes. Missed the asynch callback. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out. Thanks to Phil and GeoCodeZip for the help

```
<script>
            var usrLat = 0;
            var usrLon = 0;


            $.getJSON("https://freegeoip.net/json/", function (data) {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        zoom: 8,
                        center: {lat: parseFloat(data.latitude), lng: parseFloat(data.longitude)},
                        mapTypeControl: true,
                        scrollwheel: false,
                        navigationControl: false,
                        mapTypeControl: false,
                        scaleControl: false,
                        draggable: false,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        disableDefaultUI: true,
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                            mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'terrain']
                        }
                });
            });
        </script>
```